# Android Theme is inactive after update

Tags: android, themes

I updated android plug-in in eclipse and after that when I open any layout xml file, it says missing theme, and layout in not showing anything,

from the last combo box I'm choosing Android 2.2 and it starts showing the layout correctly, but again after closing it and reopen it the same problem happens.

I checked manifest file and realized that all the options are active except Theme.
[image]

any suggestion?? thanks...

Comment: Even I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by selecting the Android version from the drop down which is at the right corner below the create button.

I hope this solves it out for you too.

Comment: yes I'm doing that but it won't last. once I close the file and come back I should do that again.